# Inter-thread messaging implementation

Tags: java, multithreading

What I'm trying to do is have a thread write a message it received from its parent thread to an OutputStream, listen to an InputStream for the reply and then notify the parent thread with the reply. I wrote two test classes that do something similar but simpler in different ways. 
Method 1 only works when the `"before loop"` debug statement is uncommented, method 2 only prints the `"message from child"` debug statements. What am I doing wrong?

**Method 1**

```
public class Parent {
    private static int out = 0;
    private static int in = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Object locker = new Object();
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {          
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    synchronized (locker) {
                        try {
                            locker.wait();
                            System.out.println("Message from parent " + out);
                            in = out + 10;
                            locker.notify();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();

        System.out.println("before loop");
        while (out < 10) {
            synchronized (locker) {
                locker.notify();
                try {
                    locker.wait();
                    out++;
                    System.out.println("Message from child " + in);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }   
        }       
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
public class Parent {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final BlockingQueue<Integer> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {          
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Integer i = q.take();               
                        System.out.println("Message from parent: " + i.intValue());
                        q.put(i.intValue() + 10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }               
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            q.put(i);
            Integer j =  q.take();
            System.out.println("Message from child: " + j);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java API already offers that functionality; do you have a valid reason to reinvent the wheel?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // start a worker thread
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    // ask the worker thread to execute a task (
    Future<String> future = exec.submit(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(500); // simulate waiting for I/O
        return "hello from child";
    });

    // get the return value from the worker thread (waiting until it is available)
    String greeting = future.get();
    System.out.println(greeting);

    // terminate the worker thread (otherwise, the thread will wait for more work)
    exec.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Not really, I just don't know java well enough :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Method 1 you have a good recipe for deadlock, since the parent thread can perform its first `notify()` before the child does its first `wait()`.  This will result in both of them waiting, with neither able to notify.  Since it's a race condition, trivial things like print statements can affect the behaviour in practice.

Method 2 is likewise poorly designed because you have both threads writing and reading from the same queue.  Try it with two queues, one that the parent writes to and the child reads from, and the other that the child writes to and the parent reads from.