# Java: calling a method from the main thread by signaling in some way from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have an application with 2 threads (the **`main`** and another thread **`t1`**) which share a volatile variable **`myVar`**. Any ideas on how to make the `main` thread to call a method **`myMethod`** by signaling in some way from `t1` ? 
I implemented it by using ChangeListener and myMethod is called when myVar changes, BUT the method is called from **t1**, and not from the main thread (note: I need to call this method from the main thread because this is a call to a JavaScript code from Java, so for a security reason only the main thread can do so). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share some code to reflect what are you trying to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10162963/931925

Comment: Minopret, thanks for your link. It's really interesting the concept shown in there.

Comment: Wrong mindset.  One thread can't _make_ another thread call a method, and one thread should never _make_ another thread stop, or pause, or... anything.  Threads should always _cooperate_ with eacg other.   If you want your main thread to wait for some event, and then call some method when the event happens, then write code for your main thread that waits for the event and calls the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to have your main thread spin in a loop on some scalar, I would recommend one of the Atomics that java provides (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html), but you could use volatile if you wanted for this I think.

Each thread can only run sequentially - it's just the way computing works. The way you will handle this, is when the main thread spins in some sort of loop, you eventually check to see if this scalar of yours has been set, and when it has, you want unset the variable and execute your JavaScript. In this particular piece of your code, I think the Atomics have an advantage over the volatile with the use of the compareAndSet operations because using volatile can mess you up a bit between threads if you are trying to check the value in one operation and then set it again in another operation which gives the other thread enough time to set it again - meaning you may miss a call to your JS because the other thread set the variable between the main thread checking it and setting it (although the use of volatile vs Atomics may be interpreted as my opinion).

```
//main thread
AtomicBoolean foo = new AtomicBoolean(false);
while (...somecondition...){
  if(foo.compareAndSet(true, false)){
    //execute JS
  }
  //do some other work
}
```

and in your T1 thread, just call `foo.set(true)`.

If you expect main to call your JS for *each* time T1 sets `foo` to true, then you will have to block in T1 until main has unset foo, or use an `AtomicInteger` to count how many times T1 has set foo - depending on your needs.

Comment: **searchengine27**, Thanks for your comprehensive response ! As suggested I will use some of the Atomic classes detailed on your link above. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Since both tread sharing the same instance of `myVar`, you can make both thread to synchronize on the shared variable. Have `main` to wait on `myVar` notification before executing `myMethod`. Later, `t1` can notify through variable `myVar`, and the waiting thread can continue and proceed with the method call.

The following snippet fully demonstrated the idea

```
public class MainPlay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainPlay mp = new MainPlay();
        mp.execute();
    }

    public void execute() {
        Thread main = new Thread(mainRunnable, "main");
        Thread t1 = new Thread(t1Runnable, "t1");
        main.start();
        t1.start();
    }

    public Object myVar = new Object();

    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("MyMethodInfoked.");
    }

    public Runnable t1Runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized(myVar) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("[t1] sleep for 1 sec");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("[t1] Notifying myVar so Main can invoke myMethod");
                    myVar.notify();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // interupted.
                }
            }   
        }
    };

    public Runnable mainRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized(myVar) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("[main] Waiting for t1 to notify...");
                    myVar.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // interrupted.
                }
                System.out.println("[main] executing main method");
                myMethod();
            }
        }
    };

}
```

And the output is

```
[main] Waiting for t1 to notify...
[t1] sleep for 1 sec
[t1] Notifying sharedObject so Main can invoke myMethod
[main] executing main method
MyMethodInfoked.
```

Comment: **Hi Ferdinand**, thanks for solid response. This is an interesting approach !

Comment: If you like the answer, could you perhaps, accept it ? :D

Comment: @FerdinandNeman This isn't valid. The OP stated he needed to have the JS executed from the main thread. In your scenario, the main thread is not actually doing that, thread1 is (the names are a bit confusing here. assume the main thread is still main, thread1 is new Thread(mainRunnable,..., and thread2 is new Thread(t1Runnable,). To make this a valid answer, remove the encapsulating thread around the mainRunnable, and after you invoke Thread t1, then just call mainRunnable.run(), which will cause that to execute in the main thread.

Comment: @searchengine27 My answer shows the idea of one thread to signal the other thread to proceed doing something. I know, in my answer actually running 3 thread, the "main", thread 1 (i name it "main") and thread 2 (I name it "t1"). This is to give clearer picture on the underlying idea. OP can freely adjust/incorporate the the idea into his own project once he understand java multi-threading.

Comment: @FerdinandNeman I'm afraid I don't understand. If you know your answer is invalid, why not fix it? Fair enough, the OP can adapt your answer to do what he wants if he has the know-how to do so. However, that doesn't make your answer any less invalid. I'm trying to give you some help to make your answer valid...why not just take a second to fix it?

Comment: @searchengine27 Since OP already choose your answer as the correct one, there is no point for me to adjust the answer to be fit into any bodies need. I shows proper multi-threading approach and it works, at least to my expectation and understanding of what OP trying to achieve. Anyway, thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

You could use wait/notify blocks to prevent the main thread from continuing until signalled to do so.

```
static Main main = // ...
static boolean signal = false;

// t1:
// Do work
signal = true;
synchronized (main) {
    main.notify();
}

// main:
synchronized (main) {
    while (!signal) {
        main.wait();
    }
}

myMethod();
```

Comment: I think other than my explanations of how some things work under the hood, I like how this answer ultimately solves the problem better than my own. EDIT: I kind of changed my mind. I think this solution has merits, but to solve the problem most efficiently would require merging my answer with yours. I think the signaling and Atomics would be best because it would keep the JS from getting called more than once.

Comment: Holy god this has been written a year ago xD. Regardless, I think that busywaiting until your atomic condition has been set to true is a naive solution if there is nothing to be done, while there are places where this is useful, it really isn't so if you're waiting for, say a long running task. If OP thinks your answer is the best, I'd trust him/her to make the decision based on other factors that aren't mentioned in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

In case the main thread has nothing else to do, the approach proposed by @searchengine27 results in unnecessary processor load generated by this thread.

So instead going with some `AtomicXXX` class it would be better to use some of the [blocking queues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) which allow writing of data from one thread (with `put()`) and consumption of that data by the other. The main queue would block (by calling `take()` method) if such a queue is empty not using any CPU resources.

Comment: Hi MirMasej, it's interesting the angle you are bringing up. Say I implement what you mention above by using the class **BlockingQueue / ArrayBlockingQueue** and having a producer/consumer... Will I not end up in the same situation having to implement a loop anyway for the 'take()' method ?

Comment: Yes, you need a loop anyway. The main differences are: main thread doesn't consume CPU when there's no data in the queue. Secondly, in case the `t1` thread at some point in time makes two requests while main thread is processing some older request,  the first of the two new values won't be missed, which would happen with Atomic variable. BTW if you're interested in experimenting with other alternatives you can check out [RxJava](http://reactivex.io/).

Comment: I implemented it by using an **BlockingQueue / ArrayBlockingQueue**, but the **infinite loop while(true) {...}** is blocking the main thread, which is suppose to do some other things as well. Maybe I should implement a listener (Observable). Any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm glad you've made it. I have warned you in my answer though that `In case the main thread has nothing else to do` blocking queue would be good idea.  But nothing's lost yet, you may delegate JS execution to another thread and let main thread do its own business.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did and it works like a breeze. Thanks again for your comments. They were pretty insightful.